# Illustrator: Move selected items to separate Layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator

The title says it all. Is it possible in Adobe Illustrator to move selected items to new separate layers?

Comment: Can you be more clear, as you say separate layers! Do you mean you have multiple elements selected that need to be moved in to a new layer for each object?

Or if you mean you want to move already selected objects to a new (one) layer?

Comment: @Mamoon First one, I have multiple selected items that I want to move to seperate layers for each item. Let's say I have 5 items on one layer selected, I want illustrator to create 5 new layers and move every item on its own layer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well there is no direct way to have them as new layers at top level.

But what you can do is this:

1. Select the layer that contains the objects you want to move. (in image Layer 1)

[image]

2. While Layer 1 is selected press the panel menu button. Then click Release to Layers (Sequence).

[image]

3. This will create a sublayer for each object under Layer 1.

[image]

4. Select the new Layers (Layer 2, 3, 4) and drag them outside Layer 1 so they sit as top Layers.

[image]

Hope this helps you! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The option "Release to layer" is greyed out. What to do?

Answer (score 6):

Select all the objects you want to move to the new layer and cut them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Then, make a new layer and select it. You can now paste the objects you want to move to the new layer by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Using <kbd>shift</kbd> allows you to paste in place.

Comment: The objects will change location